# Anything I want to apt-get gives my an error processing mysql-server-5.1

Tags: mysql, apt, installation

I mean, WTH?
I messed up the server and I had to do a brand new reinstall purging everything, I also used `locate mysql` to check where else mysql was hiding.

When I try to install mysql-server-5.1 apt-get throws me an error saying:

```
Errors where encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And now it also trows me the error even if I want to install something completely unrelated to mysql!

Comment: So sparx.me gave a bad advice to your former question, right? Renaming the mysql directory and then purging does not work. And then you tried it manually or with force. So now you have a broken system...

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.
Anyway I ended reinstalling the system. It was a virtual box so no worries.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because the packaging system doesn't want to compound any existing damage by making other changes to the state of the system when it's in an inconsistent and damaged state.  Fix whatever's wrong with your `mysql-server-5.1` installation (there's not enough information in your question to give you advice on that, and it's a separate question that should be asked separately anyway), and then `apt-get` will allow you to do whatever else it is you want to do.

Comment: I don't have mysql-server-5.1 installed! I removed it completely, no traces in the whole system!
If I do `sudo updatedb` and then `locate mysql` I get _nothing_.
And then when I try to install mysql-server-5.1 again I get _exactly_ the same error

Comment: The packaging system thinks differently.  Deleting files off the filesystem doesn't change the packaging system's mind, either (in fact, it's entirely likely you've made things worse).  Ask a separate question about fixing your packaging state.